# how to fix "Error saving the scratchpad changes to the database"?

Tags: save, docusignapi, scratchpad

In correcting the envelope in docusign, a notification "Error saving the scratchpad changes to the database" appear.

Comment: We need more information. Are you writing code? can you share a screenshot of the error? what integration are you using? how was the envelope sent? there's very little information to help you here

Answer (score 0):

When "correcting" an envelope--updating an envelope's settings while the envelope is in-flight--it is important to lock the envelope, make the updates, then unlock it.

See [EnvelopeLocks:create](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeLocks/create)